# How to use multiple collators on sql query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm doing query on Adroid SQLite local Database. My Database uses collations.

```
... ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

I found out that the search has to be [case insensitive](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation). Example:

```
... ORDER BY name COLLATE NOCASE
```

**How can i use both collators together?**

I can also manipulate the incoming data itself if necessary. But I would like to use SQLite built-in fuctions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different collations sort values differently; it is not possible to combine them.

Android does not allow to define custom collations, so you have work with the existing BINARY/NOCASE/LOCALIZED/UNICODE collations.

If none of them fits your requirements, you have to store a normalized form (e.g., all lowercase) of your values in a separate column that you can then use for sorting.